# What is the maximum (air speed) velocity of a pixie?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, pixie

Following on from [Can a pixie fly higher than their altitude of one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15130/can-a-pixie-fly-higher-than-their-altitude-of-one)

Using a combination of feats and powers what is the maximum movement rate (and thus altitude) a pixie can reach in a single round from stationary?

No teleports mind you, that's defeating the object, it's all about velocity.

Build for level 2 please.

Bonus points if said pixie can cause an AOE style effect from the damage it takes when it crashes to the ground. (Which is kind of the idea here...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**L1 build: 42 squares**

Rogue Artful Dodger pixie

Dex 16
Int 18

(everything else is irrelevant atm).

```
L1 feat Eager Advance
L1 daily Spinning Blade leap
L1 Encounter ?
At Will 1 ?
At Will 2 ?
Theme: Animal Master - Raven
```

Basic tactic (although to do this properly you need a flying target for Spinning blade leap). First turn only. Speed = is 6+4 = 10

- Fly 10 squares with spinning blade leap
- Attack
- Fly 10 squares (speed + 2)
- Fly quickly (run) 12 squares
- AP: Fly quickly (run) 12 squares

Total: 44 squares in 6 seconds or 220 ft / 6 s = 36.67 ft/s -> 25 mph

**Level 2 build: 59 squares**

Rogue|Wizard pixie

Dex 16
Int 18 (terrible idea, but this is going to be fun)

(everything else is irrelevant atm).

```
L1 feat Eager Advance
L1 daily Spinning Blade leap
L1 Encounter ?
At Will 1 ?
At Will 2 ?
Rogue Tactic: Artful Dodger
Theme: Animal Master - Raven
L2 Feat Reckless Scramble
L2 Utility: Expiditious Retreat

Gear L1, L2 - boots of Adept Charging, L3
```

Basic tactic (although to do this properly you need a flying target for Spinning blade leap).

First turn fly speed of 10 from Eager Advance.

- **Standard:**

  - Fly 12 squares with spinning blade leap (current speed = 10, +2 from reckless scramble)
  - Attack
  - Fly 12 squares (current speed = 10, +2 from reckless scramble)
- **Move:**

  -Expeditious Retreat 22 squares (current speed = 10, +2 from reckless scramble)
- **AP:**

  - Running Charge Fly quickly (run) 12 squares (current speed = 10, +2 from running)
  - Attack
  - Shift 1 square (boots of adept charging)

Still working out gear. But here is the speed calculation

59 squares -> 295 ft/ 6s  -> 49.17 ft/s -> 33.52 mph

Comment: Soulfang of the Cheetah consumable will give a +4 power bonus to speed at level 30.  Arcane familiar plus Shared Speed gives another +1 feat bonus to speed.  Bloodied Fleetness gives another +1 untyped to speed when bloodied.  Eager advance beats both with a +4 feat to speed on the first turn.  If you have a friend with the Speed of Sea and Sky feat, that's another +2 untyped.  Fast runner gets +2 untyped when you charge or run....there sure are a lot of ways to crank up the speed.

Comment: @Ananisapta current feats give total of +4 each (Mark of Storm + 1 on each move action, Reckless Scramble +2 on each shift(converted to move) from Spinning Blade leap)

Comment: Ignore the feats, then, I was labouring under the mistaken impression that untyped bonuses from feats stacked.  There are still multiple options for allies to give you a hand, though.  Wait - Eager advance gives +4 to speed on your first turn - doesn't that then add +4 to each part of the movement, rather than the +1 from mark of storm?  Or am I missing something due to self-inflicted sleep deprivation?

Comment: @Ananisapta good point, yes it would

Comment: If anyone else has suggestions for improving this particular build (looking for extra items that boost speed, or grant free action shifts) please post here or snag me in chat. specifically L1 and L3 items