# Can a Vampire run when shifting?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

I was recently trying to optimise a character for the fastest movement possible in one turn.
After looking around, I found this vampire power:

> Unfettered Hunger
>
> Vampire Attack 5
>
> Daily; Implement, Shadow
>
> Attack: Dexterity vs Reflex
>
> Hit: 2d10 + Dex Modifier Damage.
>
> Miss: Half damage.
>
> Effect:  Until the end of the encounter, you gain a + 2 power bonus to attack rolls and a +4 power bonus to damage rolls, you can shift up to your speed as a move action, and you cannot spend healing,surges to regain hit points.

I was wondering if it would be possible for the PC to run this movement, despite this being a shift action.

Also, if anyone has any other ideas for speeding up my character, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

You get your base speed from this, if you had something that increased your speed (like say the Eager Advance feat), that would let you shift your speed.

Running is a specific type of move action that lets you move up to your speed +2, it does not increase your speed.

For ideas on how to increase your base speed, you can look at the pixie I built [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/15142/1084)

Note: anything that changes your speed, affects this, so if you're slowed, you shift 2, not your normal base speed.